# How much resources to allocate to docker

Tags: docker

I have been playing around with docker for a few months now and we are now ready to run a few production containers, and it got me into researching the infrastructure.

It let me to the question of, how much resources do I need to allocate to docker and how much should be left for the OS.

e.g. My server is 8 core 16gb ram. **How much of that should I allocate to docker?** I want to obviously allocate the maximum possible, but at what point would there be degradation of performance of the server it self?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is hard to answer, and here's why: "docker" itself doesn't really require much in the way of resources.  On the other hand, the applications that you run *using* docker will have their own requirements.

For example, if you're hosting a multi-terabyte database in a docker container, you're going to require more memory (and probably a lot more storage) than you would for, say, a single wordpress site.

If you're hosting some sort of video transcoding pipeline in Docker, you might end up consuming a lot more of your available CPU.

The only resource that Docker really consumes on its own is the storage space for images and volumes...and again, how much space you need is entirely dependent on how you're using Docker.

It all depends on exactly what you plan on doing with your system.

Comment: I am setting up a server to host applications we develop for our clients (not SaaS, but an instance/container per client).  I guess I want to maximise the number of hosted applications on this one server before having to buy another server. This is what led me to ask the question above. To answer your question, lots (maybe 100's) of not very high cpu/memory containers. So could I allocate 7 cores, and 15gb of ram to docker? What happens if the OS needs more resources? Will that affect how my containers are running as well?